# VSCode создает огромное кол-во терминалов при запуске программы на C++

Tags: c++, linux, функции, visual-studio-code, компиляция

Я делаю лабораторную работу на С++. Папка проекта состоит из 3-х файлов: "main.cpp", "Lab.h", "Lab.cpp". В папке ".vscode" я поменял только "args":

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "Lab.cpp",
            "Lab.h",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
```

Использую компилятор MinGW, операционная система Linux Ubuntu. Особенность проблемы в том, что огромное количество терминалов создается не каждый раз, программа может запуститься, как обычно.Терминалы выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в лабораторной в функциях я зачастую использую параметры по умолчанию, например:

```
void shaker(int* arr, int right, int left = 0, int directrion = 1,  std::function<bool(int, int)> comp = [](int a, int b){ return a < b;});
```

И не то чтобы это нравится редактору(программа работает):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно чтобы эти терминалы не создавались.